# How to overwrite service from lazy loaded feature lib?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We need to add custom implementation of `AccountSummaryFacade` from `@spartacus/organization`.

Before the feature libs were introduced it worked by just providing the custom implementation in a module:

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AccountSummaryFacade,
      useExisting: CustomAccountSummaryService,
    },
  ]
})
export class SomeCustomModule {}
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not work for services that belongs to a feature lib like `@spartacus/organization`.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time I found the solution in the documentation and I just want to share it with the community so that it is easier to find:

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/eaef8c61b6d9477daf75bff9ac1b7eb4/6ae18e81bc8542b8885bb10bb046d5c8.html?locale=en-US

The solution is to import the custom module also in a lazy load import style and to import the module from `@spartacus/organization` in your custom module. In our case it was:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [AccountSummaryModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AccountSummaryService,
      useClass: CustomAccountSummaryService,
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomAccountSummaryModule {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [AccountSummaryRootModule],
  providers: [
    provideConfig(<CmsConfig>{
      featureModules: {
        [ORGANIZATION_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY_FEATURE]: {
          module: () =>
            import('@spartacus/organization/account-summary').then((m) => m.AccountSummaryModule),
        },
        [ORGANIZATION_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY_FEATURE]: {
          module: () =>
            import('./account-summary/custom-account-summary.module').then(
              m => m.CustomAccountSummaryModule,
            ),
        },
      }
    }),
  ]
})
export class OrganizationAccountSummaryFeatureModule {}
```